# Conditionally revealed content and screen readers

Tags: javascript, html, select, accessibility

Pretty new to accessibility in web but been tasked with improving a page so your guidance would be much appreciated.

I have an HTML select element with a few options and each option will either reveal some additional questions or just some information. Just wondering if these conditionally revealed content has to be in some way tied to the selected option so that screen reader will announce to the user that new content has appeared on the page? I read about `aria-live` for somewhat similar implementations but not entirely sure if this is needed here? Select element and subsequent content looks like below although the toggling functionality is not yet implemented.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label for="employmentType">Your employment type</label>
<select id="employmentType">
  <option value="0">Full time</option>
  <option value="1">Part time</option>
  <option value="2">Fixed term contract</option>
  <option value="3">Student</option>
  <option value="4">Unemployed</option>
</select>

<div class="value-zero-content hidden">
  This is some information
</div>
<div class="value-one-content hidden">
  <label for="empName">Employer name</label>
  <input type="text" id="empName">
</div>

<div class="value-two-content hidden">
  <label for="contractStart">Start date</label>
  <input type="text" id="contractStart">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.